# Two datepickers are not displaying in a single htmlpage

Tags: jquery, html, css, datepicker

I want to keep two datepickers in a single html page but while running it is displaying only one date pickers .

The coding i have done is

```
 </head>
      <body>
            Issue Date(dd-mm-yyyy)<span class="star" style="color:red;">*</span>
                     <!-- <input  type="text" id="datepicker" />-->

             <script type="text/javascript"src="http://www.snaphost.com/jquery/Calendar.aspx"></script>

                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

           Expiry Date(dd-mm-yyyy)<span class="star" style="color:red;">*</span>

          <script type="text/javascript"src="http://www.snaphost.com/jquery/Calendar.aspx"></script>

      </body>
 </html>
```

I have checked this also http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Can anyone give some suggestion how to solve this problem.I am using dreamweaver 8.

Comment: type="text/javascript" src="http://www.snaphost.com/jquery/Calendar.aspx" really? what is the idea behind this?

Comment: Why not jQueryUI datepicker then ? http://jsfiddle.net/Y2WTV/

Comment: try with different id's or use single class to show date picker...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery UI

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
      <body>
            Issue Date(dd-mm-yyyy)<span class="star" style="color:red;">*</span>
                     <input  type="text" id="datepicker" /> 
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           Expiry Date(dd-mm-yyyy)<span class="star" style="color:red;">*</span>
                     <input  type="text" id="datepicker2" />
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
           <script type='text/javascript'>
               $("#datepicker").datepicker();
               $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
           </script>
      </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much  Mr. Hamed Ali Khan you it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Calendar.aspx file you have used the following code,

```
$(function () { $('#SnapHost_Calendar').datepicker({showOn:'both',buttonImage:'http://www.snaphost.com/jquery/calendar.gif',buttonImageOnly:true,changeMonth:true,changeYear:true,showOtherMonths:true,selectOtherMonths:true}); });
document.write('<input name="SnapHost_Calendar" id="SnapHost_Calendar" type="text" />');
```

Instead of,

```
$(function () { $('.datepicker_field').datepicker({showOn:'both',buttonImage:'http://www.snaphost.com/jquery/calendar.gif',buttonImageOnly:true,changeMonth:true,changeYear:true,showOtherMonths:true,selectOtherMonths:true}); });
document.write('<input name="SnapHost_Calendar" id="SnapHost_Calendar" class="datepicker_field" type="text" />');
```

Because ID can't repeated twice it must be unique. So only the calendar event not triggered for second textbox

Comment: Yes, you can modify you code instead of Id use class name. It will resolve your issue.

Comment: i got the output in other way,thanks for co-operating me.@Mr Thaangraj

Answer (score 0):

Try This Using jQuery UI

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".star").datepicker();
   });
 </script>
```